# Missing group in ggplot (using knitR)

Tags: r, plot

I want to generate Boxplots for 3x2 groups using ggplot and parsing it into a word document with knitR. The plot should look somewhat like this [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hq3Ep.png).

[image]

It works in R, but in knitR I get something like the one below where it drops one grouping variable (the "colour" in ggplot(aes()), s. below) and changes the order of the legend.

[image]

I use the following function for plotting:

```
  boxplot_t1t2 <- function(data, group, variable, time, ylab)
  {
    ggplot(data, aes(x = group, y = variable, fill = group, colour = time)) + 
      stat_boxplot(geom = 'errorbar') +
      geom_boxplot() +
      labs(x = "", y = ylab) +
      scale_fill_manual(values = c("khaki1", "mediumseagreen", "olivedrab2")) +
      scale_x_discrete(labels = str_wrap(c("", "", ""), width = 2)) +
      scale_colour_manual(values = c("black", "black")) +
      scale_colour_grey(start = 0.4, end = 0) +
      theme(...)
  }
```